# changing attribute of element - why is onchange event not fireing?

Tags: javascript, html, events

For demonstration of the problem described below see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtq6H/4/)

HTML:

```
<input type="range" id="slider_length" min="10" max="200" value="0" step="10" onchange="changeValue1();" />
<span id="slider_length_span">10 mm</span>
</br>
<input type="range" id="slider_length2" min="5" max="15" value="0" step="10" onchange="changeValue2();" />
<span id="slider_length2_span">5 mm</span>
```

JS:

```
window.changeValue1 = function()
{
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider_length");
    var span = document.getElementById("slider_length_span");
    span.innerHTML = slider.value + " mm";

    var slider2 = document.getElementById("slider_length2");
    slider2.setAttribute("max", slider.value - 5);
}

window.changeValue2 = function()
{
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider_length2");
    var span = document.getElementById("slider_length2_span");
    span.innerHTML = slider.value + " mm";
}
```

I have one range element where the user can select a value between 10 and 200 with steps of 10.
There is a second range element with values between 5 and 15 with steps of 10.

If the user changes the first range element, the onchange event gets fired (successfully), in which the "max" attribute of the second range element gets changed (by value of first element -5). So far this works fine.

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

- select any number on first range element (e.g. 150)
- select highest possible number on second range element (e.g. 145)
- reduce selected number on first range element (e.g. 150 -> 110)

**Expected behaviour:**
When the onchange Event of the first range element gets fired the "max" attribute of the second range element changes to 105. The value of the second range element still is at 145 and should go to 105 (highest possible value). Because the second range element changes, the onchange event gets fired, updating a span element which shows its value.

**Actual behaviour:**
When the "max" Attribute of the second range element gets changed the onchange event doesn't seem to fire.

**Question:** Why is the onchange event not fireing? If onchange event is not the correct event to use in this case, which event am I supposed to use?

Comment: The change event simply does not fire when the value is changed via script. One solution would be to fire the event from script as well (but that is done easier with an a little more sophisticated event handling approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a trick on your function like;

```
window.changeValue1 = function()
{
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider_length");
    var span = document.getElementById("slider_length_span");
    span.innerHTML = slider.value + " mm";

    var slider2 = document.getElementById("slider_length2");
    if ((slider.value - 5) < slider2.value) {
        slider2.value = 0;
        slider2.setAttribute("max", slider.value - 5);
        slider2.value = slider.value - 5;
        var span = document.getElementById("slider_length2_span");
        span.innerHTML = slider2.value + " mm";
    } else {
        slider2.setAttribute("max", slider.value - 5);
    }



}
```

In order to set max value of second range in your case, I have set second range to zero, set max range of slide2 and set slide2 value to possible max value. You can see working example here: **http://jsfiddle.net/wtq6H/7/**

Answer (score 1):

Onchange only checks if the value of an input changes not if any of it's other attributes change. In addition only after specific user actions like a textfield loosing focus will the browser check if a change has happend to begin with.

Why do you want to use the second event anyway? It seems like you should be able to do everything you want to do in the second event from within the first.